# How do I disagree with a flag?

Tags: support

I was inspecting a flag of [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/12447/what-is-the-most-expensive-scene-ever-shot/18207#18207) because it was low quality. It was indeed low quailty, but only because it didn't have references or numbers (factual information).

I posted a comment asking the user to provide the factual information to upgrade it from poor to acceptable.

1. What should I have done with this flag since there was a chance to salvage the answer with factual information
2. How do I disagree with a flag? I didn't see any options to do so

Here is what I see

[image]

When I click the flag or disagree button, I see this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I also don't agree so much with the heavy use of flags instead of downvotes for what are actually just bad answers, but I also see that the use of the *"low quality"*-flag [is not that easy to decide](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1206/49). I for myself think that the *"low quality"*-flag is usually unneccessary since answer quality is easily expressed through simple voting. But I also will not cast an *"invalid flags"*-flag for now, since I cannot deny the fact that this answer certainly *is* of *"very low quality"*, at least not until it garneres *"not an answer"*-flags, which would be entirely wrong, given that it definitely is a valid answer, albeit a bad one. But if you don't agree with the flag, then feel free to disagree with it.
2. As to the technical part of the question, in the [flag review section](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tools/flagged) there is a button under each individual flag reading `flag or disagree...`. Clicking it will open a window with multiple options, one of them being `it has invalid flags`. Select this one and click `Flag Answer`.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a screenshot of what I see. I don't see any other options.

Comment: @DustinDavis Like described in my answer. Click the *"flag or disagree..."* button and proceed as written.

Comment: Updated again to show the dialog

Comment: holy crap I'm not paying attention

Comment: lol you are correct. I'm not paying attention this morning >:(